# Write binary file in Java

Tags: java, matlab, io, binaryfiles

I have been facing quite some issue in translating a working `MATLAB` snippet into the respective `JAVA` looking one.

In **`MATLAB`** it works as follows:

```
fid = fopen('test.wnd','w');
fwrite(fid, -99, 'int16');
fwrite(fid, 7, 'int16');
fwrite(fid, 92, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 3, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 75.0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 75.0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 3.0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 2048, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 8.0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 340.2, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 12, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 3, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 3, 'int32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 113.4, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 0, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 27.72, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 12, 'float32');
fwrite(fid, 340.2, 'float32');

Scale = [1.0 .8 .5];
Offset = [8.0 0 0];

v = zeros(3*3,1);

for it = 1:nt
    cnt = 1;
    for iz = 1:nz
        for iy = y_ix
            for k=1:nffc
                v(cnt) =  ((velocity(it,k,iy,iz) - Offset(k))/Scale(k)*1000);
                cnt = cnt + 1;                
            end %for k
        end %iy
    end % iz 

    fwrite( fid_wnd, v, 'int16' );

end %it
fclose(fid);
```

Therefore, in **`JAVA`**, I tried this:

```
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:/Users/fperrone/Desktop/test.wnd"));
dos.writeShort(-99);
dos.writeShort(7);
dos.writeInt(92);
dos.writeInt(3);        
dos.writeFloat((float)75.0);
dos.writeFloat((float)75.0);
dos.writeFloat((float)2.4);
dos.writeInt(2048);
dos.writeFloat((float)8.0);
dos.writeFloat((float)0);
dos.writeFloat((float)0);
dos.writeFloat((float)340.2);
dos.writeInt(0);
dos.writeInt(67);
dos.writeInt(3);
dos.writeInt(3);
dos.writeFloat((float)0);
dos.writeFloat((float)0);
dos.writeFloat((float)113.4);
dos.writeFloat((float)0);
dos.writeFloat((float)0);
dos.writeFloat((float)27.72);
dos.writeFloat((float)12);
dos.writeFloat((float)340.2);
double[] Offset = {8.0, 0.0, 0.0};
double[] Scale = {1.0, .8, .5};
short v[] = new short[9];
        for(int it = 0; it < 4096; ++it){
            for(int comp = 0; comp < 3; ++comp){
                int count = 0;
                for(int iy = 0; iy < 3; ++iy){
                    for(int iz = 0; iz < 3; ++iz){
                        v[count] = (short) ((test[it][comp][iy][iz] - Offset[comp])/Scale[comp]*1000);
                        dos.writeShort(v[count]);
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
            }           
        }       
        dos.close();
```

The point is that when I link the `JAVA` output with a software the binary file is meant for, this software does not read any information, wheres the `MATLAB` output is read perfectly as expected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you compared the Java resulting binary and MATLAB resulting binary? Could it be endianness or some such shenanigans?

Comment: One issue could be you use writeInt() instead if writeShort() for the first '7' (int16 in matlab)

Comment: that was a typo, I edited.

Comment: @Shark: this could be a hint!

Comment: Java will write big-endian Integer/Short (high order bytes first), what does MATLAB do ???

Comment: Since I am working in `Windows` and since I have not specified any `machineformat` in `fwrite`, the function is writing the binary with the byte ordering my system uses, ergo I suppose `Little Endian`.

Comment: Looking at http://www.mathworks.com.au/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/284736, it suggests that MATLAB use the "Normal" endian, for Intel that is little endian ( bytes are ordered low to high) while java will use big endian (bytes written high to low)

Comment: @BruceMartin: we said the same thing :)

Comment: From the sound of thigns - i'm glad to be able to help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified the "machine format" in either fopen() or fwrite() in the matlab program, it will use the 'native' system byte ordering by default.

You need to specify your binary format while creating a file in Matlab using the "machineformat" field.

fileID = fopen(filename,permission,machinefmt,encodingIn)
fwrite(fileID, A, precision, skip, machineformat)

More information here:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html

For correct read from a java program, you need to do this: fid = fopen('test.wnd','w', 's');